# Why some characters are missing in a td?

Tags: html, html-table

I have some trouble with html. If I write a string containing <> sometimes what is between this characters is missing.

```
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd<efgh>ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td> <Input Type="text" value="abcd<efgh>ilmn"></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd<1efgh>ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br><tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd<!efgh>ilmn</td>
</tr>
```

And this is what I obtain:

User Name: abcdilmn 
User Name: abcdilmn
 
User Name: abcd<1efgh>ilmn 
User Name: abcdilmn

Here a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2txjmf6o/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bydefault all browser parse these character as a code block, if you want to use these characters the you can use their utf8 code. check updated snippet below..

```html
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td> <Input Type="text" value="abcd<efgh>ilmn"></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;1efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br><tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;!efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

It treats them like tags. If you want to see them, you should escape them.

```
<td>abcd&lt;efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the text is recognized like a tag. When you look at the rest of the code, you notice that `<td>` and `<efgh>` have the same syntax.

Just because there is no such tag this does not mean it is not handled as a tag. Ignoring unknown tags is actually a feature, so a browser may render HTML using newer standards without problems. So imagine an old browser displaying an `<audio>` tag verbatim just because it does not know it. This would be worse behaviour than not displaying it at all.

The solution is to escape the special characters using the entities `&lt<` and `&gt;`.

Below is your example adapted to use the entities.

```html
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td> <Input Type="text" value="abcd<efgh>ilmn"></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br><tr>
  <td> User Name:</td>
  <td>abcd&lt;!efgh&gt;ilmn</td>
</tr>
<br>
```

Check using `&lt; and &gt;` as above